# Quotient convexity of a function in general form

Tags: functions, solution-verification, proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

if i have 2 convex functions f(x), g(x) and g(x) positive. How to prove that h(x) is convex? which h(x)=f(x)/g(x)

Comment: i am here and i dont know how to continue..h((1-t)x1 + tx2) <= t[f(x2) / g((1-t)x1 + tx2)] + (1-t)[f(x1) / g((1-t)x1 + tx2)]

Comment: Very very wrong statement, where doe this come from?